# Is there any way to put not Base Type in Entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public Asset extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;

    private Localization currentLocalization;

    private Localization plannedLocalization;

}
```

It throws `Basic attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity'.`

I know that Entity should have Id etc, but what if I dont want to create another table, service, repository just for Localization who should be just a property, not another table.

Edit:

**Localization**:

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Localization {

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Floor.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FLOOR_ID")
    private Floor floor;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(1000)
    private int xAxis;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(2400)
    private int yAxis;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(999)
    private int zAxis;
}
```

Here I am using `@Embedded` with Attribute Overrides like:

```
    @Embedded
    private Localization localization;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="floor.id", column = @Column(name = "floor_plannedId"))
    })
    private Localization localizationPlanned;
```

but it throws:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.mrfisherman.relice.Entity.Asset.AssetEntity column: floor_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

No matter how I set name in `@AttributeOverride`

Comment: You should use [AttributeConverters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) or hibernate [Custom BasicTypes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type)

Comment: 'I dont want to create another table, service, repository just for Localization who should be just a property, not another table' - so, an `@Embeddable`?

Comment: can you show us `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @Aman - base entity contains only ID,

Comment: @crizzis - ye I've tried it before and I use it in my code in another places too but when I even use attributesoverrides it shows me that floor_id is not unique (private Floor floor is one of localization field)

Comment: Did you use `floor_id` 2 times? i.e. both for `currentLocalization` and `plannedLocalization` with the same name?

Comment: Look now at edited question, I override floor_id but it throws exception.

Comment: I think that `@OneToOne` mapping for floor will not work since `Localization` is not an entity but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due that `Localization` is not of any "basic type" that is directly mappable to any database column type. So it should either be an entity and fields of type `Localization` mapped with `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne`.

But you do not want another entity so the other option is to make it `@Embeddable`.

Assume your `Localization` is like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Localization {
    private String str;
    private Integer num;
}
```

You can flatten fields in`Localization` to the containing class by annotating it like:

```
@Embeddable
public class Localization { ...
```

and in your `Asset` tell that this field should be embedded:

```
@Embedded
private Localization currentLocalization;
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "str", column = @Column(name = "str2")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "num", column = @Column(name = "num2"))
})
private Localization plannedLocalization;
```

This would result into a table like:

```
                       Table "public.asset"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 num    | integer                |           |          | 
 str    | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 name   | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 num2   | integer                |           |          | 
 str2   | character varying(255) |           |          |
```

As you see in the table, it is now flatten. And you also see that because there is two `Localization` in your `Asset` you need to do something with the clashing column names.

`currentLocalization` can use default naming but `plannedLocalization` cannot because `currentLocalization` already reserved those column names. So that is why there is a need for attribute override.

Considering all this you might evaluate again whether you create yet another entity and use `@OneTOne` or `@ManyToOne` mappings. It depends how compled your `Localization` is.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and I also use @Embeddable in another places, the problem is that my Localization class have Floor field, and when I try to override it, throws exception. Could you take a look at edited question?